# pthread ( POSIX Threads) in visual studio 2010

Tags: c, windows, linux, pthreads, posix

I have found a Pthread program from internet and i want to run it in visual studio 2010 but I dont know how can use pthread in visual studio. the following is the program which I found:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 4096
#define NO_PROCESS 8

typedef double matrix[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];

int N;          /* matrix size      */
int maxnum;     /* max number of element*/
char *Init;     /* matrix init type */
int PRINT;      /* print switch     */
matrix A;       /* matrix A     */
double b[MAX_SIZE];    /* vector b */
double y[MAX_SIZE];    /* vector y */
pthread_barrier_t barrier;

/* forward declarations */
void work(void*);
void Init_Matrix(void);
void Print_Matrix(void);
void Init_Default(void);
int Read_Options(int, char **);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t threads[NO_PROCESS];
    int timestart, timeend, iter;
    long i;

    Init_Default();     /* Init default values  */
    Read_Options(argc, argv);    /* Read arguments   */
    Init_Matrix();      /* Init the matrix  */

    pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, NO_PROCESS);

    for (i = 0; i < NO_PROCESS; i++)
        pthread_create (&threads[i], NULL, (void *) &work, (void *) i);

    for (i = 0; i < NO_PROCESS; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    pthread_barrier_destroy(&barrier);

    if (PRINT == 1)
        Print_Matrix();
}

void work(void *pId)
{
    int i, j, k;
    long thread_id = (long)pId;

    /* Gaussian elimination algorithm */

    for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
    { /* Outer loop */

        if (thread_id == (k % NO_PROCESS))
        {
            for (j = k + 1;(j < N); j++)
                A[k][j] = A[k][j] / A[k][k]; /* Division step */

            y[k] = b[k] / A[k][k];

            A[k][k] = 1.0;
        }

        pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier); /* wait for other threads finishing this round */

        for (i = k + 1;(i < N); i++)
        {
            if (thread_id == (i % NO_PROCESS))
            {
                for (j = k + 1;(j < N); j++)
                    A[i][j] = A[i][j] - A[i][k] * A[k][j]; /* Elimination step */

                b[i] = b[i] - A[i][k] * y[k];

                A[i][k] = 0.0;
            }
        }

        pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier); /* wait for other threads finishing this round */

    }
}

void Init_Matrix()
{
    int i, j;

    printf("\nsize      = %dx%d ", N, N);
    printf("\nmaxnum    = %d \n", maxnum);
    printf("Init      = %s \n", Init);
    printf("Initializing matrix...");

    if (strcmp(Init, "rand") == 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                if (i == j) /* diagonal dominance */
                    A[i][j] = (double)(rand() % maxnum) + 5.0;
                else
                    A[i][j] = (double)(rand() % maxnum) + 1.0;
            }
        }
    }

    if (strcmp(Init, "fast") == 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                if (i == j) /* diagonal dominance */
                    A[i][j] = 5.0;
                else
                    A[i][j] = 2.0;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Initialize vectors b and y */
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        b[i] = 2.0;
        y[i] = 1.0;
    }

    printf("done \n\n");

    if (PRINT == 1)
        Print_Matrix();
}

void Print_Matrix()
{
    int i, j;

    printf("Matrix A:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("[");

        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf(" %5.2f,", A[i][j]);

        printf("]\n");
    }

    printf("Vector b:\n[");

    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        printf(" %5.2f,", b[j]);

    printf("]\n");

    printf("Vector y:\n[");

    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        printf(" %5.2f,", y[j]);

    printf("]\n");

    printf("\n\n");
}

void Init_Default()
{
    N = 2048;
    Init = "rand";
    maxnum = 15.0;
    PRINT = 0;
}

int Read_Options(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *prog;
    prog = *argv;

    while (++argv, --argc > 0)
        if (**argv == '-')
            switch ( *++*argv )
            {

                    case 'n':
                    --argc;
                    N = atoi(*++argv);
                    break;

                    case 'h':
                    printf("\nHELP: try sor -u \n\n");
                    exit(0);
                    break;

                    case 'u':
                    printf("\nUsage: sor [-n problemsize]\n");
                    printf("           [-D] show default values \n");
                    printf("           [-h] help \n");
                    printf("           [-I init_type] fast/rand \n");
                    printf("           [-m maxnum] max random no \n");
                    printf("           [-P print_switch] 0/1 \n");
                    exit(0);
                    break;

                    case 'D':
                    printf("\nDefault:  n         = %d ", N);
                    printf("\n          Init      = rand" );
                    printf("\n          maxnum    = 5 ");
                    printf("\n          P         = 0 \n\n");
                    exit(0);
                    break;

                    case 'I':
                    --argc;
                    Init = *++argv;
                    break;

                    case 'm':
                    --argc;
                    maxnum = atoi(*++argv);
                    break;

                    case 'P':
                    --argc;
                    PRINT = atoi(*++argv);
                    break;

                    default:
                    printf("%s: ignored option: -%s\n", prog, *argv);
                    printf("HELP: try %s -u \n\n", prog);
                    break;
            }
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to run it in visual studio. I know there should be included some header, but i dont know how to do it.

Please let me know from start until end step by step. I am a beginner in programming please tell me step by step...

Comment: You could install Linux on your machine. It has a quite good posix thread implementation. And it will learn you a big lot!

Answer (score 3):

http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/

The above link is for a pthreads partial implementation on Win32.  It's a little old, but it should do the job.

Comment: thanks, i have found the way to use pthread in visual studio using the link you give me.I have done all steps like add include folder and lib folder and add .ddl file.and now i have pthread header.but there is a problem. i can successfully build my project but when i go to debug it i face the following error :   ""the program cant start because pthreadVC2.dll is missing from your computer.try reinstalling the program to fix the problem"".   van you tell me about the error and how to solve it????

Answer (score 3):

Now that you've got your program compiled, you need to locate the specific dll (pthreadVC2.dll) in one of two places:

- 1) The same directory your .exe file is located in 
  OR
- 2) C:\Windows\system32 (if your OS is a 32bit windows version) 
  OR
- 2) C:\Windows\SysWOW64 (if your OS is a 64bit windows version)

Really, the "C:\Windows" in the above examples should be the actual path your windows is installed to, sometimes this is spelled out as %windir%\system32 or %windir%\SysWOW64

Answer (score 0):

A short and easy description can be found [here](http://web.cs.du.edu/~sturtevant/pthread.html)
(for all the files: *.h, *.lib, *.dll).