# Where can I download the pthread.h, semophore.h and their libraries?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

Where can I download the pthread.h, semophore.h and their libraries for C?

I need to download for windows. And also please give the linking procedure for VS2010.

Comment: One possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499074/pthread-posix-threads-in-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows got its own threading mechanism and is not dependent on pthread etc, similarly it also got semaphores (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686946(v=vs.85).aspx), but there are pthread port for windows http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/, you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Windows **does not** support `pthread` libray because windows **it's not** a `POSIX` system

The pthread is POSIX and it's available only for POSIX system like linux, BSD, Mac OS X etc... but not available for windows

You have to use portable pthread solution for windows instaed like the [solution](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) that ***Saqlain*** provide in his answer.

I did not advise to use the portable solution I advise to use the ways that your Operating system provide. And Windows has its own way to manage threads and semaphore

**BTW:** Using the POSIX pthread library is not by just include the header file `pthread.h` and `semophore.h` you have also to use the library (`*.so` or `*.a`) because it's needed in the linkage phase in your build.

Comment: Not true, there are ports for Windows, and there is Cygwin.

Comment: I do not know the ports for windows. And for the Cygwin it's a simulation of linux environment on windows. and you have to install Cygwin in each computer you want to run your binary. So in addition of binary you have to nstall cygwin with it in each computer

Comment: Also, and this is really nitpicking, pthreads is POSIX, so available on the BSDs, Mac OS X, etc, not just Linux.

Comment: @BoBTFish Could you provide links for ports of pthread on windows . this seems interesting

Comment: @BoBTFish you are right concerning the pthread is POSIX. answer updated. and I have added in the answer the portable pthread but I did not advice the OP to use I advice him to use the windows way of managing threads and semaphore that's the right way

Comment: 1. The answer still says you **can not** do this, which is not true. I'm prepared to agree you **should not** do this. 2. The question as it stands is still pretty much an exact duplicate, and as such should be closed, so the answers are somewhat irrelevant.